# Accessing attributes within a class and outside of a class

Tags: c#

Main method with some tree objects:

```
namespace Forest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Tree Fir = new Tree();
            Fir.species = "Fir";
            Fir.height = 100.0;
            Fir.trunkDiameter = 10.0;

            Tree Oak = new Tree();
            Oak.species = "Oak";
            Oak.height = 120.0;
            Fir.trunkDiameter = 12.5;
        }
    }
}
```

A tree class:

```
namespace Forest
{
    class Tree
    {
        public string species;
        public double height;
        public double trunkDiameter;
    }
}
```

I want to add an attribute as such: `public double trunkCircumference = trunkDiameter * 3.14`
But when I do that, the trunkDiameter variable isn't recognized. When adding a static modifier, it fixes, but I cannot access trunkDiameter.

I would just like to add a trunkCircumference attribute.

Comment: You seem to be confused about the differences between attributes, fields, and properties. These are specific things in c#.

Comment: I'll do a little more research, sorry if I'm using incorrect terminology, I'm a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

Since `trunkCircumference` appears to always return `trunkDiameter * 3.14`, you could define it as a property, instead of a field.

```
namespace Forest
{
    class Tree
    {
        public string species;
        public double height;
        public double trunkDiameter;

        public double trunkCircumference
        {
            get => return trunkDiameter * 3.14;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Using your code doesn't work either. A screenshot: [link](https://gyazo.com/e256076b1a4f666a594ca526fcf15582)